# How to apply for Australian visiting visa while working remotely?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, working-visas

I'm an Indian citizen and an Indian passport holder. I want to travel to Australia for a short period of 3 - 6 month). While researching for an appropriate visa I found that Visitor visa (subclass 600) should meet my profile, but here is the problem: I'm currently working remotely full time for an Australian company. While filling out the visa application online they've specifically asked for my employer details. I am worried that the visa application might be rejected seeing that my employer is an Australian company and I'm not sure how this proceed in this situation.

Please advice me how I can get a visa for 3 - 6 months. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you be working for your employer while in Australia?

Comment: @PeterM Yes, I want to continue working.

Comment: The 600 subclass visa explicitly says `You must not work in Australia on this visa.`

Comment: @PeterM Are there any other options?

Comment: You need your employer to sponsor you for the applicable Visa.

Comment: Are you sure you're working directly for the Australian company and not for a local Indian subsidiary or contractor?

Comment: @JonathanReez There are no Indian subsidiaries, I directly invoice the Australian company for my payments and its paid in USD.

Comment: Sounds like you have a contracting model, but you're not an employee of the company.

Comment: @jpatokal Yes, It's a contract.

Answer (score 6):

If you're planning to work in Australia, even remotely, a tourism or business visitor visa (subclass 600) is not appropriate.  You should be applying for the **subclass 400 short stay work visa** instead, sponsored by your employer:

https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/400-

This lets you work legally in Australia for up to three months, or in limited circumstances up to 6.

I've applied for these twice for visitors coming to work with my team, and in both cases the process was surprisingly fast and straightforward, with processing times of under a week.  Your mileage may vary.